# Magento 2.4.3 console error

Tags: magento2.4.3

How to solve the console error order tracking disabled in magento

ORDER TRACKING DISABLED. (anonymous) @ (index):159
jquery-migrate.js:23 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed with logging active, version 1.4.1

Comment: this might give you direction https://community.magento.com/t5/Welcome-to-the-Magento-Community/home-page-console-warring/td-p/458168

Comment: Thanks i will verify